# Java String to Date without time

Tags: java

I'm taking a class in Java and I need to convert a string to a date format (dd/MM/yyyy). I have been using the SimpleDateFormat to format my input, but it is showing the time, timezone and day of the week the date falls. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
Date date = new Date(); 
do{ 
    y = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
                                    "Please enter the vehicle's registration date",
                                    "Year?", 
                                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE); 
    try { 
        date = df.parse(y); 
        check = true; 
    } 
    catch (ParseException e) { 
        check = false; 
    } 
} 
while (check == false); 
return date;
```

Anyone know how I can keep the format to just the date (e.g. 12/3/2000)?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Just format it accordingly using [`SimpleDateFormat#format()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29).

```
String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(dateObject);
```

The `java.util.Date` object contains information about **both** date and time. If you want only the date part in a human representable format, then you need to format it into a `String`. Invoking [`Date#toString()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29) as you would get when doing `System.out.println(dateObject)` would only return the date in format `dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy`. Also see the linked javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar solution to @BalusC, except this one will provide a locale-dependent formatting:

```
String dateString = java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(dateObject);
```

In other words your US and EU customers will get different formatting. One they're familiar with.